# Why the wildfly-swarm-plugin tries to download the dependencies from jboss group repository no matter what I configure in settings xml?

Tags: maven, wildfly, swarm, wildfly-swarm

When I use the JBoss Wildfly Swarm Plugin it tries to download the dependencies from the repository.jboss.org maven repository, even though I set up a repository with the same id in settings.xml

```
[INFO]  --- wildfly-swarm-plugin:2017.5.0:package (default) @ my-swarm-driver ---
[INFO] Downloading: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/com/test/java-client/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata com...
```

How to force the plugin to use my enterprise repository?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up a new mirror in your settings.xml (better use the private one under HOME_DIR/.m2/settings.xml

```
<settings>
  ...
  <mirrors>         
    <mirror>
      <id>jboss-public-repository-group-axa</id>
      <name>My Mirror JBoss Public Group Central</name>
      <url>https://myserver.com/nexus/content/groups/my-group</url>
      <mirrorOf>jboss-public-repository-group</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>

</mirrors>
```